# Qemu/KVM: Protection between Guests

Tags: security, qemu, kvm, libvirt, apparmor

On http://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#securitysvirtaa it says with Apparmor there is no protection between guests. When I use libvirt under ubuntu with active apparmor to start a guest than it creates automatically policy-files for each guest. Do they meant a process specific protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparmor default only includes protection of the Host from Guest compromise.  Apparmor with libvirt adds the extra security protection needed to protect guests from each other. See [this](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/Libvirt) and [this](http://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html).